# How to traverse through the pid namespace of a container?

Tags: linux-containers, linux-namespaces, runc

I've to traverse through the process tree of the container launched in `runc` container environment.
My goal is to walk the process tree when the container is paused and call `clone` method to specific `pid` of that process tree so that it creates a new child process to it. How can i acheive this?

Comment: Do you know how `ps` and `nsenter` work?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i know something about it. but how do i call clone method to a specific process in that pid namespace while the container is paused?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica How can i execute a program in another namespace, suppose a c or any python program, everywhere the examples are like ps, ls but nothing about custom programs, i've tried to do just passing the name of a cpp object file while doing nsenter but it says file not found?